# React Native: onFocus and onBlur for custom inputs

Tags: react-native, onblur, onfocus

in my react native project I`ve created a custom input component, let's call it "CustomInput". This just returns a standard .

```js
const CustomInput = (props) => {
  return (
    <TextInput
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "white",
        padding: 10,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "#eee",
        borderRadius: 2,
        marginBottom: 12,
      }}
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      value={props.value}
    ></TextInput>
  );
};
```

I want to call it in a parent component, like:

```js
<CustomInput
  placeholder="Family Name"
  value={this.state.familyName}
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ familyName: text })}
/>;
```

How can I dynamically use the onFocus() and onBlur() method to highlight them when the user-focused it?

If I don't use a custom input I can do it like that:

```js
<TextInput
  ref={(input) => {
    this.inputFullName = input;
  }}
  style={styles.loginTextInput}
  placeholder="Fullname"
  value={this.state.fullName}
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ fullName: text })}
  onFocus={() => this.focusedInput(this.inputFullName)}
  onBlur={() => this.blurInput(this.inputFullName)}
/>;

focusedInput = (inputField) => {
  inputField.setNativeProps({
    style: { borderColor: "#4094ec" },
  });
};
```

Comment: How about forwarding the ref of `TextInput` in your custom component? It enables you to use ref of `TextInput` In the parent of your custom component? Watch this doc. <https://en.reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is a mix-up, between forwarding the ref and passing the function:

```js
const CustomInput = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <TextInput
    ref={ref}
    style={{
      backgroundColor: "white",
      padding: 10,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: "#eee",
      borderRadius: 2,
      marginBottom: 12,
    }}
    onChangeText={props.onChangeText}
    placeholder={props.placeholder}
    value={props.value}
    onFocus={props.onFocus}
    onBlur={props.onBlur}
  ></TextInput>
));
```

Call in the parent component:

```js
<CustomInput
  ref={(input) => {
    this.inputLastName = input;
  }}
  placeholder={i18n.t("enterLastName")}
  value={this.state.familyName}
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ familyName: text })}
  onFocus={() => this.focusedInput(this.inputLastName)}
  onBlur={() => this.blurInput(this.inputLastName)}
/>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add them in props:

```js
const CustomInput = (props) => {
  return (
    <TextInput
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "white",
        padding: 10,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "#eee",
        borderRadius: 2,
        marginBottom: 12,
      }}
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      value={props.value}
      onFocus={() => props.onFocus()}
      onBlur={() => props.onBlur()}
    ></TextInput>
  );
};
```

And call it like:

```js
<CustomInput
  placeholder="Family Name"
  value={this.state.familyName}
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ familyName: text })}
  onFocus={() => yourFunctionForOnFocus()}
  onBlur={() => yourFunctionForOnBlur()}
/>;
```

Comment: Yes you can. But then you are missing the the reference of the choosen inputField. This would work online with one field, but not if you have it more than once -> it would always highlight the last one rendered...